# For any $a_0$, $b_0$, such that $a_0 > b_0$, $a_n = (a_{n-1} + 1)^2$, and $b_n = b_{n-1}^2$, does $a_n$ always eventually overtake $b_n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Or is there some $a_0$, $b_0$ for which this does not hold?

Comment: With your definition is $a_n > b_n$ for *all* $n = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$.

Comment: Definition does not say $b_0 \ge 0$

Comment: The hypothesis $a_0>b_0$ does not make any difference

Comment: I take the question to read "$a_0<b_0$". Then it makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_0=-1, b_0=-2.$ Then $a_1=0, b_1=4.$

We have $$(0\le a_n \le \frac {b_n}{4}\land\; b_n\ge 4)\implies (0\le a_{n+1}\le \frac {b_{n+1}}{4}\land\; b_{n+1}\ge 4).$$

Proof: $$ \frac {a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}=\frac {(a_n+1)^2} {b_n^2}=$$ $$=\frac {a_n^2}{b_n^2}+\frac {2}{b_n}\cdot  \frac {a_n}{b_n} +\frac {1}{b_n^2}\le$$ $$\le \frac {1}{16}+\frac {2}{4}\cdot \frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{16}=\frac {1}{4}.$$

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no: not always does $a_n$ overtake $b_n$. To justify that, I will just give a general idea of the proof (a sketch, if you want), and you can fill in the details as you please. To begin with, let's notice that the hypothesis $a_0>b_0$ does not make any difference here, since all that matters for the sequence $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is $|b_0|$, and it can be chosen arbitrarily large by making $b_0$ arbitrarily negative.

Now, notice that for $n\geq 1$, $b_n=|b_0|^{2^n}$, and that "$a_n$ eventually overtakes $b_n$" $\iff \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n}< 1$, in case this limit exists. Therefore, we are interested in the following limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{b_n}{a_n} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|b_0|^{2^n}}{a_n}=:\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n$$
If we can choose $a_0$, $b_0$ such that the latter limit is greater than or equal to $1$, then we are done. For that, let's take a look at the limit of $(x_n)^{\frac{1}{2^n}}$:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)^{\frac{1}{2^n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|b_0|}{(a_n)^\frac{1}{2^n}}=\frac{|b_0|}{\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)^\frac{1}{2^n}}$$
Observe now that we can recursively determine the sequence of $\tilde{a}_n:=(a_n)^\frac{1}{2^n}$, namely,
$$\tilde{a}_0 = a_0,\ \ \tilde{a}_{n+1}=(\tilde{a}_n^{2^n}+1)^\frac{1}{2^n}$$
This sequence (for $n\geq 1$) is nonnegative and non-decreasing for any choice of $a_0$. In particular, it has a limit (either a positive constant or $+\infty$), but it can be checked that it is a Cauchy sequence, so the limit is a positive constant, say $C$.

Finally, taking $b_0$ such that $|b_0|>C$,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n)^{\frac{1}{2^n}}=\frac{|b_0|}{C}>1,$$
hence,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty,$$
and we conclude that $a_n$ does not overtake $b_n$.

P.S.: I feel like a much simpler proof can be done, but this is the one I came up with.

Comment: +1/ You might see my Answer for comparison.